# Upload media with unofficial Instagram API

Tags: ruby, curl, upload, instagram

I'm writing a script that uploads photos to Instagram by schedule. The official Instagram API does not allow media uploads. I found that the only solution today is to use [unofficial API](https://github.com/mislav/instagram/wiki). So, I'm trying to use it but it responds with 301 error to all my requests.

Ruby code:

```
url = 'https://instagr.am/api/v1/accounts/login/'
RestClient.post url, { username: 'username', password: 'password', device_id: '0000' }, user_agent: 'Instagram'
# RestClient::MovedPermanently: 301 Moved Permanently
```

Or curl:

```
$ curl -k --data "username=username&password=password&device_id=0000" --header "User-Agent: Instagram" https://instagr.am/api/v1/accounts/login/
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me to find an error in my requests or suggest a better solution how to upload media to Instagram?

Answer (score 0):

Instagram has put in place a signature that is required for "unofficial" API requests.. if you can find out how to generate that signature then you'll be golden... I've got a general understanding of how it's done by reviewing their android version's source code but I never quite cracked the process and haven't had the time to spend on it..

There are some third party clients out there that can do it but IG seems to be pretty good at detecting and deleting those photos.. and often banning the account.